# jQuery AJAX: why is .error() method deprecated in favor of .fail()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

If you read the link [here for .ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) they say:

> jqXHR.fail(function( jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown ) {}); An
>   alternative construct to the error callback option, the .fail() method
>   replaces the deprecated .error() method. Refer to deferred.fail() for
>   implementation details.

Why is `.error()` method deprecated in favor of `.fail()`?

Comment: http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/9399

Comment: 10 points apiece :-) for all of those jQuerites involved in the switch to .done .always .fail. Once you get used to it, it is much easier and very slick.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The two options are equivalent.

However, the promise-style interface (.fail() and .done()) allow you to separate the code creating the request from the code handling the response.

You can write a function that sends an AJAX request and returns the jqXHR object, and then call that function elsewhere and add a handler.

When combined with the .pipe() function, the promise-style interface can also help reduce nesting when making multiple AJAX calls:

```
$.ajax(...)
    .pipe(function() { 
        return $.ajax(...);
    })
    .pipe(function() { 
        return $.ajax(...);
    })
    .pipe(function() { 
        return $.ajax(...);
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

This is actually talking about the method on [deferred](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.fail/). It is saying that the deferred object used to have a error method but was deprecated because fail makes more sense in that context.

The object that the ajax() call returns implements a promise interface so you can call fail() and done() and then().

You could also use the option 'error' to define a failure callback function before you make the ajax call. Note that this is not a function but an option.